# Graphical addition of velocities in Minkowski spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, vectors

In what follows we are in the domain of special relativity.

Consider a reference frame with two velocity vectors $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ with their tails at the origin. How do I represent relativistic combination of these two velocities graphically on a normal sheet of graph paper?

Let me explain a bit more. Suppose $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ are time-like vectors with length $p$ and $q$ respectively. I choose an origin on the graph paper, call it $O$, and draw two hyperbolas: $t^2-x^2=p^2$ and $t^2-x^2=q^2$. From the origin I draw lines along the known directions of $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, and their intersection with the previously mentioned hyperbolas (and in that order) determine the points $P$ and $Q$. Then I draw the vectors $\vec{OP}$ and $\vec{OQ}$ on the graph paper. Which *graphical construction* will now give me the sum of these two vectors on the graph paper? What if one of the vectors is space-like or null?

P.S. I have looked at this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279208/four-vector-addition-in-minkowski-space) but it doesn't answer my question. Searching the internet throws up papers on "gyro-vectors", but so much math seems pointless just to learn how to add vectors on graph paper.

Comment: You're seeking graphical velocity addition, then; this isn't really clear until the "gyro-vector" hint in your last paragraph. In short, you're seeking a graphical construction to represent Lorentz transformation composition. Do you just want to do this with collinear boosts, *i.e.* on a $1+1$ dimensional Minkowski plane, or do you want to add general boosts?

Comment: Everything you've written about 4-vector addition is correct. Lorentzian signature doesn't affect the addition rule. However you shouldn't expect vector addition to correctly describe the relation between relative velocities of frames of reference, be it 3-velocities in Euclidean signature or 4-velocities in Lorentzian.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus: *be it 3-velocities in Euclidean signature* Why not?

Comment: I edited the title and question heavily since in its original form it seemed to assume that addition of velocity four-vectors was the way to combine velocities in SR.

Comment: @BenCrowell you know the relativistic velocity addition law. It is not $\vec{v} + \vec{w}$. Which was my point.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus My question was about any two time-like vectors, not necessarily velocity 4 vectors. I was thinking more in terms of adding momentum 4-vectors, but then these are nothing but scaled velocity 4 vectors.

Comment: @Deep I will try to communicate my point to you again. Mathematically, adding vectors is just a plus. All coordinates are added. This is what you would use when you calculate the total momentum of the system, for example. However you can't use this to pass between moving reference frames.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I do not wish to pass between moving frames. I wish to find the total momentum 4-vector of a two particle system (say) confined to one spatial dimension, so that a graph paper may be utilized to draw their momentum 4-vectors. Even in this case the graphical construction of a parallelogram on the graph paper would not suffice, I suppose.

Comment: @Deep I see, I didn't realize that was your question, sorry.

Comment: Aha - so then you should edit your question to talk about the calculation of total momentum. You really threw me raising gyrovectors.  Also "epresent relativistic combination of these two velocities" pretty strongly implies Lorentz transformation composition (of course, that's not the only interpretation but I'm just saying this is what the phrase evokes for me). Because this *is* one instance when you do simply add the momentum vectors to find the total momentum and you do it just like regular vectors on graph paper. 4-Momentum is conserved and linearly additive. The time components add ...

Comment: ... to give the total energy, the spatial components add to give you the relativistic momenta. Also, 4-vectors "add" like four dimensional graphical arrows in the sense that they are tangent vectors to the spacetime manifold, and the space of tangents is a linear space (vector space in the mathematical sense): any linear combination of 4-vectors, which can be represented by graphical arrows, is also a valid 4-vector. For velocities, of course, not all 4-vectors can be 4-velocities, since the latter are required to have unity Minkowsky norm. 4-velocities are thus somewhat analogous to ...

Comment: ... quantum states - you can either identify four velocities with rays in the tangent space or you can do the usual thing and say that non-null (non lightlike) velocities all have unit norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For relativistic velocity addition in the plane, there is a highly elegant graphical construction detailed in:

[John A. Rhodes and Mark D. Semon, "*Relativistic velocity space, Wigner rotation, and Thomas precession", *Am. J. Phys.* **72** #7, July 2004](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0501070)

That is, this construction lets you visualize the composition of any two members of the group $\mathrm{SO}(1,\,2)$. It gives you *both* the combined velocity *and* the Wigner rotation (recall that the addition of two non-collinear boosts is not a boost, but rather a boost combined with a rotation, as I discuss further [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99459/26076)).

I have built a Mathematica demonstration which draws the graphical construction at:

[Selena Amy Routley, "Boost Composition and Wigner Rotation in Rhodes-Semon Rapidity Space", Wolfram Demonstrations Project Published: November 2, 2015](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BoostCompositionAndWignerRotationInRhodesSemonRapiditySpace/)

Basically, one represents boosts in the Poincaré disk model of Hyperbolic space: the boost of rapidity $\eta$ making an angle $\phi$ with the $x$ axis is represented by the complex number $z = e^{i\,\phi}\,\tanh\left(\frac{\eta}{2}\right)$. I sketch the construction below:

[image: Boost Addition]

Our first boost is the ray $\vec{OA}$, and the addition triangle is the hyperbolic triangle $\triangle OAB$. The second boost bears the composite along the circular arc $AB$, where the blue tangent to the arc at the point $A$ is in the direction of the second boost. The arc is uniquely defined by this tangent and the lemma that all such arcs make right angles with the unit circle at the two points where they meet the unit circle. The composed boost is the point $B$. The Wigner rotation is the angle subtended by the arc $AB$ at the circle's center $C$.

If $z_1$ is the first boost, followed by the boost represented by the point $z_2$, then the combined boost's rapidity and direction is represented by the point:

$$z_3 =\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1+z_2\,z_1^\ast}\tag{1}$$

and the accompanying Wigner rotation is, as stated above, the angle subtended by arc $AB$ at the circle center $C$. The arc $AB$ defines the trajectory of the motion state if a frame initially moving inertially relative to the observer as described by $z_1$ is acted on by a constant acceleration in the direction of the blue tangent.

Of course, the method is not wholly graphical, but then you also need to calculate hyperbolic tangents to find the points $z_1$ and $z_2$ anyway, but it does give you a great deal of intuition for both the change of motion state under constant acceleration. It's actually very like doing impedance transformation calculations with a [Smith Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_chart), which is also a graphical calculator for a Möbius transformation of $z_2$ in the form of equation (1). Here, as in the Smith Chart, you could simply use a nomogram to transform between velocities and rapidities to find the correct points on the chart. In fact, you can use a rotated unmodified Smith Chart for your calculation, because one set of the two orthogonal families on the Smith Chart are precisely geodesics in the Poincaré disk - *i.e.* circles that meet the unit circle at right angles.

If you are really purist, you can maximize graphical construction one of two ways.

1. Note that $|z_1+z_2|$, $|z_1|$ and $\left|1+z_2\,\frac{z_1^\ast}{z_1}\right| = \left|1+z_2\,\exp(-2\,i\,\arg(z_1)\right|$ are all readily found by graphical construction given vectors representing $z_1$ and $z_2$, thus the ratio $|z_3|=\left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1+z_2\,z_1^\ast}\right|$ is readily found by real multiplications and divisions. One then simply needs to construct the intersection of the circular acceleration arc and the circle $|z|=|z_3|$ with a compass;
2. Begin with the point $z_2$ and then note that it is mapped to the composite boost point $z_3$ by the composition of the following operations in the following order: $z\mapsto \exp(-2\,\arg(z_1))\,z$, $z\mapsto 1+z$, $z\mapsto z^{-1}$, $z\mapsto \left(1-{z_1^\ast}^{-1}\right)\, z$, $z\mapsto z + {z_1^\ast}^{-1}$. There are standard graphical straightedge and compass constructions for all of these involving the Circle of Apollonius and parallelogram construction (where ${z_1^\ast}^{-1}$ and $1-{z_1^\ast}^{-1}$ are also found from $z_1$ by the same constructions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking of the more general case of addition of _any_ time-like 4-vectors on a graph paper, and not necessarily velocity 4-vectors. For example, addition of momentum 4-vectors of two particles restricted to move in one spatial dimension. But then momentum 4-vectors are just scaled velocity 4-vectors. The math in your answer is a bit hard on me, and I will have to give it enough time to fully understand it. I am only a beginner in special relativity. Thanks again.